# Add Azure D drive (temporary storage) to a migrated VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, hypervisor

Any VM created in Azure is given a D drive; a temporary storage drive attached to the hypervisor; which gives better performance than the data disks as it's closer to the VM's compute resources.  This comes at the cost of the contents not being persisted should the VM be deallocated / move to  different host.

When you use Azure Migrate to move a VM from a non-Azure solution (e.g. an on-premise vmware solution) into Azure, no such temporary drive is created.

Is there a way to add such a drive to a migrated VM, so we can move the VM's pagefile there, and thus improve the performance of the migrated VM?

Comment: What VM size are you using? Some of them have no temporary disk

Comment: Thanks @SamCogan; Many are `Standard B2ms`; which it seems should include a [16GB D drive](https://instances.vantage.sh/azure/vm/b2ms) / does when we create a fresh VM, but doesn't show up on the migrated devices.

Comment: I'm wrong... It seems `Hide Empty Drives` was enabled on these servers; so I wasn't seeing the drives though they were there (spotted when I went to the computer's disk management to check for the volume and saw it was there & configured).  The pagefile wasn't automatically moved to this new drive, so I had to go in and set D drive to System Managed and C back to None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Per @SamCogan in the comments, check that the VM has a temporary drive.
- Check whether the drive really is there; i.e. `Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced' 'HideDrivesWithNoMedia'` should return `0`.
- Optionally use PS to check: `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem  | Format-Table Root, Description -AutoSize`.